# Swagger codegen maven plugin with path variables and request params OpenApi produces not working code

Tags: spring, swagger, swagger-codegen, swagger-codegen-maven-plugin

I'm facing a problem with swagger codegen generatered stubs. 
I have 2 services. First exposes REST api with two methods with path var and request param:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/start/{pathVar}/operators", params = "login")
    public Operator getOperatorByLogin(
                @ApiParam @PathVariable Long pathVar, 
                @ApiParam(required = true) @RequestParam  String login) {
        return operatorRepository.findDistinctByLogin(login);
    }
```

and

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/start/{pathVar}/operators", params = "ids")
    public List<Operator> getOperatorsByIds(
                @ApiParam @PathVariable Long pathVar, 
                @ApiParam( allowMultiple = true) @RequestParam List<Long> ids) {
        return operatorRepository.findAllByOperatorIdIn(ids);
    }
```

There are 2 endpoints with same URLs but diffrent params. Spring-web framework works with that.
Next, I genereate OpenApi json and get 2 paths:

```
"/start/{pathVar}/operators{?ids}": ...
"/start/{pathVar}/operators{?login}": ...
```

Then, Im trying to generate with swagger-codegen-maven-plugin stubs for that endpoints and then I'm facing the problem.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Map has no value for '?login'

URLs in that form are hardcoded in generated classes.

```
(...)
final Map<String, Object> uriVariables = new HashMap<String, Object>();
uriVariables.put("pathVar", pathVar);
String path = UriComponentsBuilder.fromPath(
"/start/{pathVar}/opeartors{?login}").buildAndExpand(uriVariables).toUriString();
(...)
```

throws exception because of lacking of login map key-value in uriVariables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your should be careful on your definition file (.json or .yml) to define the correct type for your paramaters as there is two kind of params :

1. Path parameter (GET /users/{id})
2. Query parameter (GET /user/findByLogin?name=myUserLogin)

Those two have two differents declaration in OpenAPI

**1) Path parameter**

```
paths:
  /users/{id}:
    get:
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: id   # Note the name is the same as in the path
          required: true
          schema:
            type: integer
            minimum: 1
          description: The user ID
```

**2) Query parameter**

```
parameters:
    - in: query
      name: myUserLogin
      schema:
        type: integer
        description: The number of items to skip before starting to collect the result set
```

For more detailed check the [official docuementation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/#path-parameters)